# Pointwise convergence of a functional series.

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\text{sin}x)^j}{j} \text{           (}   x \in (0,\pi))$$

How would I go about showing this is pointwise/uniformly convergent?

I seem to think it is not.

In the case that $x\in(0,\pi) - \{\frac{\pi}{2}\}$, we have;

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\text{sin}x)^j}{j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(\text{sin}x)^j =\frac{\text{sin}x}{1-\text{sin}x} $$

however when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1)^j}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j}$$ which is divergent.

I am not doing very well here.

Comment: You used the geometric series. It is only valid if $|\sin(x)|<1$. For $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ this is cleary not the case.

Comment: Even though I treated it as a separate case? My aim was to show that it was not pointwise.

Comment: You are right that it is not convergent.

Comment: but my method is wrong?

Comment: No it is right, i just thought you were confused about the contradiction between the geometric series and the direct method :).

Comment: Thanks :) and so the functional series is not uniformly convergent. Brilliant!